# Webapp that uses "UIScrollView" in html

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I would like to make a webapp that uses the "UIScrollView" xcode-function but in html.

There's no problem making a html page that puts a bunch of images in one row.. I just want to make a iphone horizontal scroll with swipe gesture to show the next image.

Can this be made?

Comment: can you clarify? are you making a web app (html)? or native (UIScrollView)?

Comment: I want to make a web app (html)! the UIScrollView function is just the reference of how I want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to watch for touchstart and touchend (or touchmove) to figure out the direction, then just replace the image with the next/previous. Here are some links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

Untested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var startX;
var endX;
var pic=0;
var pics = ['pic1.png','pic2.png','pic3.png'];
document.getElementById('picture').setAttribute('src',pics[pic]);

function touchStart(event){
    startX = event.touches[0].pageX;
}

function touchEnd(event){
    endX = event.touches[0].pageX;
    deltaX=endX-startX;
    if(deltaX>0){
        next();
    }
    else{
        prev();
    }
}

function next(){
    pic++;
    if(pic>pics.length){pic--;}
    document.getElementById('picture').setAttribute('src',pics[pic]);
}

function previous(){
    pic--;
    if(pic<0){pic++;}
    document.getElementById('picture').setAttribute('src',pics[pic]);
}
</script>
<style>
#pictureFrame{height:460px; width:320px; top:0; left:0;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="pictureFrame"><img ontouchstart="touchStart(event);" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);" id="picture"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I added some code that might help, but I didn't test it so you may need to add some preventDefault's (mentioned in the docs) or other debugging.